# Visual Studio Code add C compiler specific keywords

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, styles

I have to use a specific compiler for some projects (pretty old ones). When I open any of the source code files I may find compiler specific keywords like *sdata*, *bit*, *xhuge* etc.

Is it possible to tell the C/C++ extension to ignore the keywords, so no error is given?

Visual Studio Code would show an error for the following line.

```
    static uint8 sdata someVariable = 0;
```

I would like to ignore the shown error for *sdata* in this case and in best case assign a specific color to it.

Thanks in advance

---

```
    #include "someheader.h"                     // @Yunnosch-header
    static uint8 sdata someVariable = 0;
```

---

The suggestions of @Yunnosch would work for other systems too.
Here is an example of how I did it for the Eclipse CDT-Parser.

```
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // CDT Parser specific definitions, hide unknown keywords from CDT Parser
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    #ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
    #define sdata
    #define bit
    #define xhuge
    ...
    #endif // __CDT_PARSER__
```

Is there a similar #define for VSCode C/C++ extension parser, that could be used for this purpose?

Comment: Can you somehow tell when the old and when a new compiler is used? Is there maybe a macro set for the old one? If you can make a compiler-specific macro then it would be easy.

Comment: When you mention errors, you mean that VS Code editor shows some errors, not the compiler, correct?

Comment: @Gerhardh correct, VS Code shows an error. The compiler does its job, as it knows how to handle the specific keywords.

Comment: @Yunnosch there is no "new" or "old" compiler, I have to use just KEIL C166 compiler. Yes I can include header files, but how does that help with VSCode? May you give an example for your idea?

Comment: So you could include a header file so that its content becomes applied before that line of code with the unwanted symbols? Please provde a [mre] of that, e.g. with a "myfix_headedr.h" being included. Then I think the solution is easy.

Comment: @Yunnosch - don't understand what you trying to force me to - sorry.

Comment: I want you to present code which demonstrates your problem and also provides a foundation for a solution. As far as I understand you could include an additional headers. Since I consider that the most convenient foundation for the solution I have in mind, I ask you to show your code with an `#include "myheader.h"` (and a statement that it is empty or its content as part of the MRE). Ideally quote the error you get without solution.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have the strong feeling, that there is a big misunderstanding here. 
The code compiles fine. Only VSCode C/C++ Extension is not aware of compiler specific keywords like sdata etc. I already showed the code above. Only missing the red line of VSCode, which tells me that it doesn't know about sdata. 
I try to understand your intention of adding a header file to a source code which compiles fine. Do you suggest to use the preprocessor to "#define sdata " as empty statement for VSCode? If so just give me a push to the documentation and I will try it, otherwise I don't get it.

Comment: To `#define sdata ` as empty statement is exactly my idea. Yes. It requires a way into the visibility for whatever tool you want to avoid warnings from. In my experience, it is not always possible to add a header include, or to have editing rights on an existing header. That is why I kind of wanted to see that you can add an `#include` to the code which gives you trouble. (Kind of funnny to call it a Yunnosch header, but that is kind of fair, after you must have felt pestered by me.... ;-) ). I wanted to experiment with ways to get that header into visibility. It is easier than I thought.

Comment: Since you already second guessed my plan, please try whether it helps and (since you guessed it and probably rejected that idea already) explain what keeps you from doing that. One of your other comments questions my "new/old" header phrasing. Yes, I admit that I was thinking of a compiler change or update. My experience with VScode extensions is minimal. I might be totally wrong or simply unaware of what is going on there. So just tell me. Yes, misunderstanding likely - and I take it on me. I also realise now, that the single line of shown code can be seen as MRE. Als my bad.....

Comment: Ok after syncing up again, I did something like this for eclipse already. There is indeed a #define which tricks __CDT_PARSER__ (Parser of Eclipse) to ignore all weird keywords of the compiler. Basically I can do this also for VSCode. Thing is that I wasn't able to find a #define like __CDT_PARSER__ for the VSCode extension - any hints here?
What confused me about your suggestion was, that I was asking to extend the  VSCode extension. So I may was on the wrong track at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution working for me in this case:

I needed to add the following defines within the c_cpp_properties.json-file

```
"defines": [
                "bit=uint8_t",
                "uchar=uint8_t",
                "ulong=uint32_t",
                "far=/**/",
                "idata=/**/",
                "sdata=/**/",
                "huge=/**/",
                "xhuge=/**/"
            ]
```

So solved